# How to get the value of an object in a multidimensional list in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have created a multidimensional list of objects in my program because I want to store different data in it while running. How do I retrieve the value of a specified index in that multidimensional list?

The multidimensional list looks like this:

```
List<List<List<object>>> list = new List<List<List<object>>>();
```

Comment: This can lead to a `List<List<List<Problems>>>` for you in the long run. There might be better storage alternatives than a 3-dimensional list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the value of any index in the list you need to insert the index of each dimension in brackets.

In this case you will need to do this:

```
object valueInList = list[0][0][0];
```

For each dimension you need to enter another bracket, i.e. for a five-dimensional list it goes as following:

```
List<List<List<List<List<object>>>>> list = new List<List<List<List<List<object>>>>>();
object valueIn5DList = list[0][0][0][0][0];
```

With the same way you can also assign values to the specified index in the list.

```
List<List<List<List<int>>>> list = new List<List<List<List<int>>>>();
list[0][0][0][0] = 36;
```

You can replace the zeros in the brackets with the desired index, of course.

Keep in mind that the first index is for the parent list, the second is for the list in the parent list, etc.

P.S. You can always create a custom class for each data type in such cases so that you make more readable code overall.